# Group By only if column has a NULL value

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a `View` in `SQL` which displays orders and the products on that order, and also the list that the products have been assigned to. What i am trying to do is use a `Group By` if the products have not been assigned to a list but display the ones that have been assigned individually.

For example my `View` looks like this:

```
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| fkOrder | fkProductID  |  fkListID   |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
|   1     |     10       |    NULL     |
|   1     |     10       |    NULL     |
|   1     |     10       |    NULL     |
|   1     |     10       |     1       |
|   1     |     10       |     1       |
|   2     |     20       |    NULL     |
|   2     |     20       |    NULL     |
|   2     |     20       |    NULL     |
|   2     |     20       |    NULL     |
|   2     |     20       |     1       |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

But i would like it to look like this:

```
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| fkOrder | fkProductID  |  fkListID   |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
|   1     |     10       |    NULL     |
|   1     |     10       |     1       |
|   1     |     10       |     1       |
|   2     |     20       |    NULL     |
|   2     |     20       |     1       |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

At the moment i have been able to get this result using a `Group By`:

```
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| fkOrder | fkProductID  |  fkListID   |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
|   1     |     10       |    NULL     |
|   1     |     10       |     1       |
|   2     |     20       |    NULL     |
|   2     |     20       |     1       |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

I have been browsing for similar questions to mine but i still haven't been able to find an answer that works for me. I am aware that i may of read an answer that could be what i need but due to my inexperience in `SQL` I don't know. So i thought i would just ask myself.

I have tried removing the `Group By` from the `fkListID` Column but i get the error : `'fkListID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the Group By clause` so i tried all of the other options provided within the drop down other than `Group By` but couldn't get the desired result.

I feel instead that it's somewhere along the lines of having a `Group By WHERE fkListID IS NULL` but keep getting syntax errors.

Or possibly a `CASE WHEN` statement on a column but again i just don't know.

Any links to a question that has an answer appropriate to me, or an answer, would be great.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using

Comment: eg. for SQL Server, a ROW_NUMBER with expression in GROUP BY would be one solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I thought I had with the `SQL` tag but obviously not sorry. I realise now the `SQL` tag is for the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As presented, your data has no primary key.  You can do this using `union all`:

```
select fkOrder, fkProductID, fkListID
from myview
where fkListID is not null
union all
select distinct fkOrder, fkProductID, fkListID
from myview
where fkListID is null
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, got the desired result perfectly. So quick i have to wait to accept your answer...